# Reporting off of an in memory data store?

Tags: sql, azure, redis

I need to generate reports based on a dataset pulled from a third party API, but I can't store the data on disk. (If not storing the data were not a requirement, I would be storing the data in a relational database, and writing a query to join several tables to generate the export as a CSV, for instance.) I've been reading about Redis and I wanted to know if that is a potential solution here as a temporary datastore? Or would I have a hard time putting the tables in the dataset together? If not Redis, what is the recommended way to cache data for reporting purposes in an Azure environment?

Comment: Rather than closing the question, could we migrate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm filling in a lot of the gaps with assumptions, but to answer your question, yes.

Azure Redis Cache could be used to run your reports "in memory" generally speaking.

For the solution, "it depends" on:

- the type of data
- how you ingest the data
- the type of reports you are trying to run

You have a platform that can run reports with Azure Redis Cache, but you still need to model the data properly to build your reports.  Redis is not a relational database.  Without more details, you should start here: https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro

Comment: I think that's the key, as I did more research, is that Redis is not a relational database. But I found that SQLite has an in-memory option, which could be another option. Thanks.